# Disable CDC on a Table but keep the CDC table for history

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, cdc

Currently I have CDC enabled on a table DATA_Sale.    I want to disable the logging of any new changes but want to keep the CDC for records.   Is this possible?

Comment: Change data capture mechanics vary significantly between database products. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I need an answer that would work in sql server 2008 r2 and above

Comment: Are you wanting to disable CDC for a table or the entire database? if just the table you absolutely will lose all the data. It is stated quite clearly in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-disable-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

The process of disabling CDC on your table will cause the corresponding system table that's been capturing the changes to be dropped, as noted in the documentation that @SeanLange posted in the comments, [sys.sp_cdc_disable_table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-disable-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

But knowing that the system table will go away just means you have to plan for that.

First, you probably want to [stop capturing new changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sys-sp-cdc-stop-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), unless you have other capture instances running:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_stop_job @job_type = N'capture';
```

Now make a copy of the system table, and port your data over to it. 'SELECT ... INTO ...` will do. You can tweak the structure later if you need to.

Then go ahead and disable the capture.